# Best function to get a cell from the same row as another cell on a separate sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

What is the best function to get a cell from the same row as another cell on a separate sheet. On sheet 1, A2 is a lead id and B2 is a name. On sheet 2, if I put in the lead id on A2, I want the name to autopopulate in B2. The function I used is =IF(A2=Leads!A:A,Leads!B:B," ")   Now, it works fine with my first two leads but then it returns the false value on all the others. It has worked a couple times but it seems really glitchy. Any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use a vlookup function for this.  Try putting the following formula into Sheet2 cell B2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

vlookup will work (Chris Moore answered with this)

Personally I prefer using index/match because if you alter the structure of the sheet by inserting or removing columns the formula adapts better and also because index match can lookup columns in any order and uses more precise ranges

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

For a more in-depth explanation there is one here: https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/